# VueJS - v-for loop with object key name created with index

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How would I create a v-for loop in Vue with the image array name being created as a string template?

So let's say I have 5 arrays of bedroom images coming back from the api with specific key names:

```
data() { 
  return {
    Bedrooms: 5,
    // values set in created(){}
    Bedroom1Images: [], 
    Bedroom2Images: [],
    Bedroom3Images: [],
    Bedroom4Images: [],
    Bedroom5Images: [],
  }
}
```

And I want to loop each image in each array, but also, loop the whole thing so I only have one "bedroom-wrap" element in the template that gets printed in a loop.

Something like this, though this syntax doesn't work.

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in Bedrooms" :key="index"> // master outside loop
  <div class="bedroom-wrap">
    <label>Bedroom {{ n }}:</label>
    <ul class="photos">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in `Bedroom${n}Images`" :key="index">  // name array using `n` from outside loop?
        <a data-fancybox="bedrooms" :href="item.thumbnails.full.url">
          <img :src="item.thumbnails.large.url" alt="Bedroom Image" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to put your images in a separate object:

```
data() { 
  return {
    Bedrooms: 5,
    // values set in created(){}
    BedroomImages: {
      1: [],
      2: [],
      3: [],
      4: [],
      5: [],
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your template you can do `BedroomImages[n]`:

```
<div v-for="(n, index) in Bedrooms" :key="index"> // master outside loop
  <div class="bedroom-wrap">
    <label>Bedroom {{ n }}:</label>
    <ul class="photos">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in BedroomImages[n]" :key="index">  // name array using `n` from outside loop?
        <a data-fancybox="bedrooms" :href="item.thumbnails.full.url">
          <img :src="item.thumbnails.large.url" alt="Bedroom Image" />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap the arrays into and an object then you can work as we want.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.7/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="(n, index) in Bedrooms" :key="index"> // master outside loop
    <div class="bedroom-wrap">
      <label>Bedroom {{ n }}:</label>
      <ul class="photos">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in Images[`Bedroom${n}Images`]" :key="index"> {{item}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      Bedrooms: 5,
      // values set in created(){}
      Images: {
        Bedroom1Images: [1, 2],
        Bedroom2Images: [1, 2],
        Bedroom3Images: [],
        Bedroom4Images: [1, 2],
        Bedroom5Images: [],
      }
    }
  }
})
```

A working example of you code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tuhin47/916pxcg0/)

Comment: thank you. This is basically what I ended up doing :)